# CSS transform transition animation redraw bug in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation, transform

I have encountered a bug in Chrome where under some conditions, a transition animation of a transform fails to animate properly.  If there's a workaround (besides using Firefox which works), I would love to know about it.  Here's an example that should show a 1s animation of the grass in the image, but instead shows a white screen before snapping the final layout:

```js
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("outer").style.transform = "scale(21)", 500)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 450px;
  height: 450px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  transform: scale(20);
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.imagery {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="outer" class="outer">
    <img class="imagery" src="https://i.etsystatic.com/6111470/r/il/1e8576/1046914582/il_1588xN.1046914582_8vh4.jpg" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `width:5;height:5;` what kind of unit are you looking for here? Probably the answer to why Chrome is bahaving badly. Also, please use CSS classes instead of styling inline.

Comment: Thanks, I made the snippet a bit cleaner to read, but the problem is the same.  My guess is it has something to do with the large virtual size of the image when scaled but Firefox and even Safari handle it properly.

Comment: Weird. It works with smaller values on scale on Chrome. Could be an optimization thingy? Seems like a Chrome bug anyways.